# Lombok Immutable: Constructor to make deep copy of parameters

Tags: java, functional-programming, immutability, lombok

How can I get a constructor that assigns a copy of constructor arguments to the fields, to make the instance truly immutable? The below class has `@Value` annotation but this isn't immutable as its the properties are not: (The question is not specific to immutable `Collections`, I just used it to demo a mutable DS. I am looking for any mutable bean in place of `List` here, which, say is coming from a library and is not in my control)

```java
@Value
class ImmutableBean {
    List<String> props;
}
```

```java
    @Test
    void checkImmutability() {
        var props = new ArrayList<String>();
        props.add("abc");
        var immutableBean = new ImmutableBean(props);
        System.out.println(immutableBean.getProps()); // abc
        props.add("pqr");
        System.out.println(immutableBean.getProps()); // abc pqr
    }
```

Comment: Just copying on construction isn't sufficient, you have to copy any field value before returning in getters, too.

Comment: Can you accept one of the below answers or explain why those answers doesn't work?

Comment: Hi! I have replied in the comments of the answers, please check.

Answer (score 0):

For Singleton class you need to use `@Singular` and mark your Collection fields as `private final`

```
import lombok.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Builder
class ImmutableBean {

    @Singular
    private final List<String> props;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> props = new ArrayList<>();
        props.add("abc");
        ImmutableBean immutableBean = ImmutableBean.builder().props(props).build();
        System.out.println(immutableBean.getProps()); // abc
        props.add("pqr");
        System.out.println(immutableBean.getProps()); // abc
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is not specific to `Collections`, I just used it to demo. How can I achieve if a mutable bean is present in place of `List`?

Comment: Follow same process to make those beans immutable mutable and then use them or clone them whenever you need to inject them in the ImmutableBean's object @GopalSAkshintala

Comment: This might not work with objects that are out of my control like the ones coming from external libraries.

Answer (score -2):

A class that is annotated with lombook [@Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) makes **all fields are made private and final by default, and setters are not generated.** Which means once the object is created, it is immutable and you cannot override properties of that class using setters method, for example

```
@Test
void checkImmutability() {
    var props = new ArrayList<String>();
    props.add("abc");
    var immutableBean = new ImmutableBean(props);
    System.out.println(immutableBean.getProps()); // abc
    immutableBeansetProps(new ArrayList<>());  //compile time error

}
```

So lombook `@Value` annotation will make property as immutable, so you cannot override that object with another object like my above example, But you can update the same object

```
var props = new ArrayList<String>();
props.add("abc");
var immutableBean = new ImmutableBean(props);
System.out.println(immutableBean.getProps().hashCode()); // object1
props.add("pqr");
System.out.println(immutableBean.hashCode()); // object1 (same object)
```

The only way to avoid this is you need to create immutable objects of those properties, for example you can create immutable list

```
var immutableBean = new ImmutableBean(Collections.unmodifiableList(props));
```

> @Value is the immutable variant of @Data; **all fields are made private and final by default, and setters are not generated. The class itself is also made final by default**, because immutability is not something that can be forced onto a subclass. Like @Data, useful toString(), equals() and hashCode() methods are also generated, each field gets a getter method, and a constructor that covers every argument (except final fields that are initialized in the field declaration) is also generated.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not about setter. It's about how to avoid mutating properties of the immutable class

Comment: why not create immutable list and assign to it `Collections.unmodifiableList(props)` @GopalSAkshintala

Comment: But this is not specific to `Collections`, I just used it to demo. How can I achieve if a mutable bean is present in place of `List`?

Comment: If you have mutable bean, make that class also annotate with `@Value` then it becomes immutable , You should always show the clear example you are facing an issue

Comment: Yes, I knew that, but what if that class is coming from a library not in my control?

Comment: I don't think so there is way, but you can wait for better answers @GopalSAkshintala